# PuTTY SSH Connection to a Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop, Pressing Enter (either) in a Man page sends 'ESCOM' instead of CR/LF

Tags: ssh, putty, keyboard

I'm trying to perform a search in a manpage, which requires the Enter key to achieve. However pressing it displays the word ESCOM instead of the desired function.

The Enter key works as it should in other areas such as the command line, or vim.

Couldn't see anything in PuTTY options other than a setting under "Terminal" labelled "Implicity CR in every LF" however enabling this has no effect.

The only related info I could find was at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/40905 however this thread seemed to fizzle out without any solution, and the reporter was experiencing the issue in seemingly many applications, whereas I can only replicate in 'man'.

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: Actually it seems I am having trouble with vim now, which is odd as it wasn't occuring earlier, not sure exactly what I'm doing differently.

Trying to :wq in vim creates a new line with 'M' in it, in the same fashion as the vim keys 'OM' would do.

EDIT 2: Ok, I've just noticed that if I use my laptops FN + Enter, I'm able to press Enter.

This is still not ideal, but at least I can save my vim changes now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PuTTY Settings > Terminal > Features > CHECK Disable Application Keypad Mode

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your man command is having issues, see the man man page.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_man.htm

Specifically, it seems that your `less` command is having issues.

-P pager
Specify which pager to use. This option overrides the MANPAGER environment variable, which in turn overrides the PAGER variable. By default, man uses /usr/bin/less -isr.

Hitting Ctrl-J should get around the issue for now, see:

https://bugs.maemo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6009

Also, this issue may be related to which enter key your keyboard maps to:

https://superuser.com/questions/142579/unix-less-problem-with-enter-key-on-numeric-keypad

Comment: Sorry, keep coming back to this problem and realised I shouldn't have marked your reply as the definitive answer, apologies if that's naughty. Currently however, problem still not solved, although you did help me "cope".

Comment: Not a problem, I'll vote up the question to see if it can get some more views.